# Seq.iter fails to iterate the sequence created with seq.collect and sequence expression

Tags: f#

I've had a bug in F# code that I have reduced to the following minimal reproduction sequence, but now I don't understand why it works that way.

```ml
let duplicate element =
    [ element; element ]

let passThrough (sq: seq<_>) =
    use it = sq.GetEnumerator ()
    seq {
        while (it.MoveNext ()) do
            yield it.Current
    }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =
    [0; 1]
    |> Seq.collect (duplicate)
    (* |> Seq.toArray // When uncommented - works as expected. *)
    |> passThrough
    |> Seq.iter (fun i -> printf $"{i} ")
    0
```

When the `Seq.toArray` call is uncommented, it produces the result I expect, i.e. iterates the sequence pipeline and prints `0 0 1 1`. However with that line commented out, the code just finishes without printing anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I conferred with one of our experts at F# Slack (thanks R. C.), and was advised that a proper implementation of `passThrough` should look like this. The enumerator is then properly disposed when the while loop exits. The problem with the original implementation is that the enumerator is disposed at a point in time before the `while` loop exits, if ever.

```
let passThrough (sq: seq<_>) =
    seq {
        use it = sq.GetEnumerator ()
        while (it.MoveNext ()) do
            yield it.Current
    }
```

Comment: I was also later given a possible explanation as to why it worked, with the flaw, in the one scenario  but not the other. I won't try to pass on that, but rest assured there's a reasonable explanation.

Comment: In the original code, the enumerator is *always* disposed before it gets used. The `use` guarantees that `Dispose` is called before the function returns, and the sequence won't be used until after the function has returned. 

As to why a disposed enumerator would still work in some cases, you'd have to dig into its implementation.

Comment: I believe you may be right, so I changed the answer to at least not contradict this.